# How to set accessibility options like "Reduce Motion" for XCTest UI tests

Tags: ios, xctest, xcuitest

For an XCTest UI test, I would like to programmatically set some accessibility options that are normally set in Settings.app, taking [Reduce Motion](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202655) as an example. The setting can be queried like this:

```swift
// UIKit
if UIAccessibility.isReduceMotionEnabled {
    …
}

// SwiftUI
@Environment(\.accessibilityReduceMotion) private var reduceMotion
```

These are read-only though. I also couldn't find an API in `XCUIApplication` to set these accessibility flags.

Did I miss an API that would help here? Do I need to launch the Settings app in my test and let the test navigate to the Reduce Motion switch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't miss anything; XCUITest doesn't have any hooks into Settings.

> Do I need to launch the Settings app in my test and let the test navigate to the Reduce Motion switch?

Yes. The bundle ID is `com.apple.Preferences`.